# CGAffineTransformRotate и размер одного UIView внутри другого

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, uiview

Приложение на iOS. Есть внутри `view` другой объект типа `UIView` по размерам первого. Так вот второй объект поворачивается внутри первого при помощи `CGAffineTransformRotate`, при этом мне надо, чтобы второй не вылезал за границу первого, а размер его уменьшался, чтобы вписываться в эти рамки. Как это сделать?

Comment: а надо изменять размер динамически или один раз рассчитать худший вариант и уменьшить до этого размера?

Comment: изменять размер динамически, объект поворачивается и его надо сразу подстраивать под размер первого

Comment: а что то уже пробовали?

Comment: а поворот анимированный или просто дан новый трансформ и надо размер изменить?

Comment: объект поворачивается при повороте айфона; насколько повернулся айфон, на такой же угол повернулся и объект, с этим проблем нет

Answer (score 1):

У тебя однозначно должен быть угол на который ты поворачиваешь, пусть он будет `A`, попробуй сделать масштабирование со следующим коэффициентом (ниже `Coef` - коэффициент масштабирования):

```
B = (A % pi/2),
Coef = cos(min(B, pi/2 - B))
```

Answer (score 0):

Начал что то мутить, но нет времени закончить. вот что получается пока что:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) UIView *parent;
@property (nonatomic) UIView *childView;
@property (nonatomic) double transform;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.parent = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    self.childView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.parent.bounds];
    self.parent.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.childView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    self.parent.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
    [self.view addSubview:self.parent];
    [self.parent addSubview:self.childView];

    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(rotate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}


- (void)rotate
{
    self.childView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.childView.transform, M_PI/180);

    double angle = atan2(self.childView.transform.b, self.childView.transform.a);
    double hor;
    double ver;

        self.childView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        hor = fabs(self.childView.frame.size.width*sin(angle)) + fabs(self.childView.frame.size.height*cos(angle));
        ver = fabs(self.childView.frame.size.width*cos(angle)) + fabs(self.childView.frame.size.height*sin(angle));

    double coefficient = MIN(self.childView.superview.frame.size.width/hor, self.childView.superview.frame.size.height/ver);
    self.childView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.childView.transform, coefficient, coefficient);

}


@end
```

Comment: познавательно, хоть это не то, что я хотел, но все равно спасибо, да и вопрос я некорректно задал